# User was deleted; which answer disappeared?

Tags: support

I just lost two points (which bothers me not at all) because a user was removed. I believe that the only way for this to happen is that the user had posted an answer to one of my questions—an answer that I had accepted. That does concern me. So I have some questions:

- Am I correct in my analysis about where the -2 came from and and did the user's posts all disappear along with the user?
- If so, is there a way to query the system to find out what question of mine no longer has an accepted answer?
- Is there a way to recapture the information in the now-gone answer?

Comment: The 2 points is the *net change from all votes*. You could have received an upvote from the user, while you downvoted some of their posts, where the net change comes down to +2.

Comment: Or I guess maybe they voted for you on a day where you rep-capped and so it only made a difference of 2?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Ah. I hadn't thought of that. However, is the most likely explanation the one I offered? Is there a way to tell if an accepted answer to one of my questions disappeared?

Comment: @TedHopp: no, there isn't. Even moderators don't get to see what user this was.

Answer (score 5):

If a post had been removed when the user deleted their account, reputation changes from the removal of the post would not get rolled up into the "User was removed" event. It would tell you exactly which post was removed and (since you're above 10k) link you directly to it.

The user removed event itself is simply the reversal of the sum of all the votes *that user* had cast toward you. To expand off my previous statement, an accept vote *you* cast (earning you a +2) would not be included because that's *your* vote and not theirs. So whatever user was deleted, their votes toward you earned you a net of 2 reputation.